# Passwordless ssh failed when login using username

Tags: ssh, centos-6, openssl, ssh-keys

I was trying to setup Hadoop and was stumbled on passwordless ssh to localhost.

I am getting a password prompt when trying to connect using `ssh username@hostname` format.
But there is no problem connecting to the machine like `ssh localhost` or `ssh hostname.com`. Tried `ssh-copy-id user@hostname` but it did not work.

Using CentOS 6.3 as normal user, I neither have root access or am a sudoer so editing any files like sshd_config is not possible (not even cat the sshd_config file contents).

I hope the user login is possible since I can do login without password to localhost, right?

Please advise,

Here is the ssh debug output.

```
[user@hostname.com ~]$ ssh -v user@hostname.com

OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010

debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config

debug1: Applying options for *

debug1: Connecting to hostname.com [::1] port 22.

debug1: Connection established.

debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/identity type -1

debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type -1

debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa type 2

debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3

debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*

debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0

debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3

debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent

debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received

debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none

debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none

debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent

debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP

debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent

debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY

debug1: Host 'hostname.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.

debug1: Found key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:1

debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct

debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent

debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS

debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received

debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent

debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received

debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password

debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex

debug1: No valid Key exchange context

debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information

Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_500' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information

Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_500' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey

debug1: Offering public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa

debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-dss blen 434

Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.

debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/identity

debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa

debug1: Next authentication method: password

user@hostname.com's password:
```

Comment: If it works without putting in the username, why do you want to put the username in?  Or are you connecting to a different account, in which case you'll need your public key in the authorized_keys of the other account as well

Comment: the login attempt is not manual. It seems the script/program is trying to ssh to localhost using the fully qualified username, like user@hostname. There is no manual control over the process, afterall that is why a passwordless (local) ssh access is wired for. Let me see if I could modify the script or something like that...